# Capture UIImage from UIView doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to capture Image from custom View which has got mask layer using
 `[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` but it doesn't work. The image's shape is rectangle but it should be custom. Here is code from custom  UIView and below it there is code from capture image.

```
@implementation ViewForAnn
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
        mask.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"customPin"] CGImage];
        mask.frame = self.bounds;

        self.layer.mask = mask;
    }

    return self;
}
@end


UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(32.0, 37.0));
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
customAnnotationView.image = img;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Could you help me to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(yourView.frame.size, yourView.opaque, 0);
[yourView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *imgView =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: It is perfectly working. Can I know what is the problem you are facing using this code ?